# TYPO3 Every Page is opened in a new window

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I've got a new TYPO3 Page and have the problem that every menu link is opened in a new Windows. How can I fix that?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set below typoscript code in your main TS configuration file.

```
intTarget = _self
extTarget = _blank
```

Comment: The settings are `config.intTarget` and `config.extTarget`. Instead of setting the first one to `_self`, you can also try  to clear it.